# relative path using typeRoots vs. baseUrl in TypeScript tsconfig.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

This tsconfig.json configurations works as expected:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"typeRoots": [
  "./node_modules/@types",
  "./node_modules/suman-types/dts"
],
```

but this one does not

```
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "node_modules/suman-types/dts"
  ],
```

does anybody know why? I am trying to figure out if baseUrl has something to do with it.

Comment: To note: For me, in a monorepo setting, `typeRoots` is resolved relative to the `tsconfig.json` location. So if you set it in `extends`, it won't work. Similar to how `baseUrl` cannot be inherited from an extended config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to figure out if baseUrl has something to do with it.

No.

You need relative path starters in typeRoots if the path is not simple (i.e. includes some `/`)

Comment: that's a shame, seems unnecessary that `node_modules/x` would fail but `./node_modules/x` would succeed.